# Is there an asynchronous source function for Flink?

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-flink

My source function has a frequency control whereas I can adjust the data rate that it flushes data to the next operator. I was measuring the data rate per operator using Prometheus+Grafana. Then I started to generate data at the speed of 100 rec/sec. On the grafana dashboard was showing about 90 rec/sec. Then I increased the data rate to be 200 rec/sec. However, the Grafana dashboard is actually showing 12 rec/sec. I was imagining that the backpressure was holding the data. But the Flink dashboard does not show I am having backpressure.

So, when checked the Flink code for `StreamSourceContexts.collect(T element)` there is a sync block there. I suppose that it is there to ensure the orderliness of events. But, what if I call the `StreamSourceContexts.collect(T element)` inside my SourceFunction using a Future? Am I going to experience out of order on the events? Is there a Source Function that allows me to push events in an asynchronous way?

```
    @Override
    public void collect(T element) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            output.collect(reuse.replace(element));
        }
    }
```

My source function:

```
public class OrdersSource extends RichSourceFunction<Order> {
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Order> sourceContext) {
        try {
            while (running) {
                generateOrderItem(sourceContext);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void generateOrderItem(SourceContext<Order> sourceContext) {
        try {
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(dataFilePath);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                // I would like to put an async thread here
                // Thread newThread = new Thread(() -> {
                //     sourceContext.collect(getOrderItem(line));
                // });
                // newThread.start();
                sourceContext.collect(getOrderItem(line));

                // sleep in nanoseconds to have a reproducible data rate for the data source
                this.dataRateListener.busySleep(startTime);

                // get start time and line for the next iteration
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            reader = null;
            stream.close();
            stream = null;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Please make sure they are available at [" + dataFilePath + "].");
            System.err.println(
                    " Follow the instructions at [https://docs.deistercloud.com/content/Databases.30/TPCH%20Benchmark.90/Data%20generation%20tool.30.xml?embedded=true] in order to download and create them.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question (or what you are trying to do). But the purpose for the sync block in sources is to synchronize event production with checkpointing, in order to provide exactly-once guarantees.

Comment: I would like to use an async thread when I call `sourceContext.collect(getOrderItem(line));` (I edited the question) because I cannot generate data faster than 200 rec/sec. Maybe there is something wrong on my source function. But I think if I use an async thread the backpressure strategy of Flink will end up consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: is there some relation between `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);` or `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);` with the source function that can affect somehow the throughput?

Comment: What version of Flink are you using? The source interfaces have changed a lot with Flink 1.11.

Comment: Flink 1.10.1. Is there a good improvement related to the source function and throughput?

Comment: The lock was removed, which might help if you are having problems with lock contention.

Comment: See [FLIP-27](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface) for details.

Comment: That is great! I will test. Tks